# Problems displaying table inside a shape in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to put a table inside a rectangle to showing information about the temperature of a land.

The problem is the table doesn´t display, when I inspect my browser, I can see the table in the HTML code.

In this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uv64k4qj/), I've put the code to show I want to do.

I don´t know if I am doing something wrong, I´m new in d3.js.

This is some code that I use to make the table.

```
var margin  = {top: 25, right: 15, bottom: 50, left: 55},
  width       = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height      = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svgContainer = d3.select(".dashboard")
          .append("div")
          .attr("class", "col-lg-6")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  svgContainer.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 10)
          .attr("y", 10)
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height)
          .style("stroke", "#B5B5B5")
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("stroke", 1);

  svgContainer.append('svg:foreignObject')
          .attr('font-family', 'FontAwesome')
          .attr("x", 40)
          .attr("y", 25)
          .attr('font-size', '100px')
          .html(function(d){ 
            return "<i class='fa fa-sun-o' id='imageTemp'></i>";
          }); 

  svgContainer.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 160)
          .attr("y", 40)
          .attr("width", 250)
          .attr("height", 120)
          .attr("fill", "#D8D8D8");

  var table = svgContainer.append("table")
          .attr("class", "table-bordered");

  table.append("thead")
          .selectAll("th")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("th")
          .text(function(d){
            return "Week "+d.week;
          });

  table.append("tbody")
          .append("tr")
          .selectAll("td")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("td")
          .text(function(d){
            return d.temperature;  
          });


  svgContainer.append("text")
          .attr("x", (width / 2))             
          .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
          .attr("class", "title") 
          .text('TEMPERATURE - '+data[0].land);
```

I appreciate some help that you can give me, Thanks!

Comment: I don't think SVG elements accept `<table>`. You will have to position table as an overlay above the SVG element.

Comment: I was looking at information and it does !, and I try to position but I can´t do it

Comment: I am going to check it out, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use an HTML element like `<table>` in an SVG, it needs to be inside a `<foreignObject>` (just like you did with the FontAwesome element).

```
var table = svgContainer.append("svg:foreignObject")
          .attr("x", 160)
          .attr("y", 40)
          .attr("width", 250)
          .attr("height", 120)
          .append("xhtml:body")
          .append("table")
          .attr("class", "table-bordered");
```

See this forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qogxmwov/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you! :)